# Add Like button to Microsoft front page website

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I'm trying to add the like button to my webpage which I build on Microsoft front page. I used the "get code" website and copy and pasted the html options to my page. But I can't see anything at all for most, the only one that will show me anything is the Iframe one but that just says "cannot open page."
Am I supposed to be changing the URL before hitting 'get code'? Or is there a way to paste the ready made code so that it shows up on my webpage that I'm just not doing correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Lindsay, for the like button you need to past the URL of your fan page, app or webpage into the code generator then click get code.  The generator encodes your url for use with the iframe button.  From there you can just paste into your site.  I use the below script and use php to encode all my urls before the button is drawn on my pages.

**encoded url sample.**

https://shawnsspace.com/plugins/TimeLineGallery.php?pageid=135669679827333

```
https%3A%2F%2Fshawnsspace.com%2Fplugins%2FTimeLineGallery.php%3Fpageid%3D135669679827333
```

---

```
> <iframe
> src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=  **YOUR_Encoded_URL**  &amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=311&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;'.$ColorScheme.'&amp;font=tahoma&amp;height=20"frameborder="0"
> allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden;
> width:90px; height:21px; margin: 3px;"></iframe>
```

Sometime i encode urls on the fly at http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Just paste the url in and encode it.  Then paste into your like button iframe code.